# Error in UseMethod("cld") : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "c('emm_list', 'list')"

Tags: r

Trying to run the

```
cld(posthoc, alpha=.05, Letters=letters)
```

code to get letter values for my data, but producing this error:

Error in UseMethod("cld") : 
  no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "c('emm_list', 'list')"

[arcdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89C5g.png)

Code as follows

```
install.packages("car")
arcdata<- read.csv(file.choose()) 
arcdata
dput(arcdata)
str(arcdata)
library(ggpubr)
plot<- ggline(arcdata, x="preg", y="arc", color = "herd",
    add =c("mean_se", "dotplot"), palette= c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
plot


model1<-lm(arc~herd*preg, data = arcdata)
anova(model1)

plot(model1, 2)

aov_residuals<-residuals(object = model1)
shapiro.test(aov_residuals)


plot(model1, 1)
leveneTest(arc~herd*preg, data= arcdata)

install.packages("lsmeans")
install.packages("multcompView")
library("lsmeans")
library("multcompView")

posthoc<-lsmeans(model1, pairwise~herd*preg, adjust="tukey")
posthoc

cld(posthoc, 
    alpha=.05,
    Letters=letters)
```

The last (cld) section of the code is not producing expected letter groups, is it possibly something to do with the alpha=.05?

Comment: I think `cld(posthoc[[1]])` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
posthoc<-lsmeans(model1, ~herd*preg, adjust="tukey")
```

Comment: Can you elaboraty why?

Comment: It seems to be due to the lsmeans to emmeans transition, and the pairwise comparison. If you run the cld() on either herd or preg it should work, but trying to test the interaction effect seems to fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
posthoc<-emmeans(model1, pairwise~herd*preg, adjust="tukey")
```

See the output of 'posthoc', you find two parts ($emmeans and $contrasts).
Or you can use `names(posthoc)` to get it.

`contrasts` should not be included

So use:

```
CLD(posthoc$emmeans, 
    alpha=.05,
    Letters=letters)
```